# Missing apk using IOIO for android

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, apk, ioio

I have been trying to get the HelloIOIO example running for ages now. It really looks good now. All dependencies are met. All the Libraries built succesfully. (All this thanks to this awesome page: https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Eclipse-Troubleshooting)

But when I want to start the app on my phone I get this:

```
[2014-02-03 19:34:33 - HelloIOIO] Android Launch! 
[2014-02-03 19:34:33 - HelloIOIO] adb is running normally. 
[2014-02-03 19:34:33 - HelloIOIO] Performing ioio.examples.hello.MainActivity activity launch 
[2014-02-03 19:34:33 - HelloIOIO] Uploading HelloIOIO.apk onto device '172.16.10.103:5555' [2014-02-03 19:34:34 - HelloIOIO] Installing HelloIOIO.apk... 
[2014-02-03 19:34:45 - HelloIOIO] Success!
```

### [2014-02-03 19:34:46 - IOIOLibAndroid] Could not find IOIOLibAndroid.apk!

```
[2014-02-03 19:34:46 - HelloIOIO] Starting activity ioio.examples.hello.MainActivity on device 172.16.10.103:5555 
[2014-02-03 19:34:47 - HelloIOIO] ActivityManager: Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=ioio.examples.hello/.MainActivity }
```

The funny thing is though that in the actual IOIOLibAndroid-Project is a ioiolibandroid.jar-File (As I said - it is compiling perfectly)

Please help me :)

Comment: Do you still need assistance on this?

Comment: I found some help here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ioio-users/WmWrdpyjc8U

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found some help here: 
groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ioio-users/WmWrdpyjc8U